# Know the checkbox selected if it created dynamically - Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I click a button I'm trying to know what `checkbox` is selected. The problem is that the checkboxes are created dynamically with a `for loop` in my template.

**html**

```
<form action="#" method="post" target="#">
    {% for node in Last_val_nodes %}
        <input type="checkbox" class="nodeRuta" name="{{node.0}}">{{node.0}}<br>
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$('#filtrar_btn_map').click(function(){
    if( $(".nodeRuta").is(':checked') ) {
        var node = $(".nodeRuta").attr("name");
        alert(node);
    }
});
```

`Last_val_nodes` is a list like `[['node1',1,2],['node2',4,5],['node3',7,8]]` and with my code the `alert` is always showing `node1`, whatever checkbox is selected.

I tried with `var node = $(this).attr("name");` but it's not working too. Can somebody help me, please?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `:checked` selector and `length` to find if *any* of the checkboxes have been checked.

That being said, depending on your needs, it would make more sense to either loop over all the checked items directly:

```
$('#filtrar_btn_map').click(function() {
  $(".nodeRuta:checked").each(function() {
    var node = this.name;
    console.log(node);
  }
});
```

Or alternatively you can use `map()` to build an array of the selected values:

```
$('#filtrar_btn_map').click(function() {
  var values = $(".nodeRuta:checked").map(function() {
    return this.name;
  }).get();
  console.log(values);
});
```

Comment: One more question, If I want only one checkbox checked? In other words, do not allow more than one selected, can be done with this code? (If it's difficult or to much long don't worry) Thank you very much.

Comment: In that case use radio buttons, not checkboxes